# Catch Clause Never Reached

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I don't understand why the catch clause in the following PowerShell code is never reached.

In this scenario I am able to retreive the SPSite object perfecly fine but accessing the AllWebs property will result in an immediate, non-catchable error `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`.

```
$Url = 'SiteURl...'

$SiteCol = Get-SPSite $url

 try {
     $wbs = $SiteCol.AllWebs
 }
 catch {
    # catch is never reached!
    Write-Error ("{0}`n`n" -f $_)
    return
 }
```

PowerShell reports `$wb.GetType()` as

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    SPWebCollection                          Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection
```

Typing in the variable $wbs will show the same error message `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation` as does `$web | get-member`

This is very odd PowerShell behavior which I don't understand.  Why is the catch clause never reached?  Why can I access the Type of my $wbs variable but cannot access the members or the variable itself?

**Update 1**

```
$Url = 'SiteUrl'

$SiteCol = Get-SPSite $url

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

 try {

    $wbs = $SiteCol.AllWebs
    Write-Host "Site Returned"

    $wbs  # <----- Error here!
    Write-Host  "Done"
 }
 catch {
    # catch is never reached
    Write-Host ("Error")

 }

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
```

This is the output when executing this code

```
Site Returned
Exception has been thrown by the target of
 an invocation.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  .\Run-Get-SPWebInfo.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Run-Get-SPWebInfo.ps1], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Run-Get-SPWebInfo.ps1
```

**Update 2   RESOLVED WORKAROUND**

I can't explain this at all but if someone can I'll consider it answered!

Wrapping the call in it's own function allowed my main code to catch the error as expected.

```
function Test-AllWebs{

    param([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $site)
    $wbs = $SiteCol.AllWebs
    $wbs
}


$Url = 'SiteURl...'

$SiteCol = Get-SPSite $url

 try {

    Write-Host "Site Returned"

    Test-AllWebs -site $SiteCol

 }
 catch {
    Write-Host ("Error caught!")
 } finally{
    Write-Host  "Done"
 }
```

Comment: Is it a terminating error?

Comment: What is `$ErrorActionPreference`?

Comment: $ErrorActionPreference is "Continue"

Comment: Not it does not teminate until I access the variable.

Comment: I'll update my code with $ErrorActionPreference but the result is the same.

Comment: Does `$wbs = $SiteCol.AllWebs -ErrorAction Stop` do anything?

Answer (score 0):

In powershell the exception must be a terminating error to trigger the catch sentence, the easy way is to set the $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'.

Comment: In my Update 1 i am setting the $ErrrorActionPreference to Stop just prior to executing the problem code and then resetting back to Continue.  I am expecting to catch the error but have not found a way to do so yet.

Comment: this is very odd, I'd modify the getter of that property to return itself if its not null, then just call it and check for null value

Comment: Any sample code for modifying the getter?  I am not familiar with that.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The target of invocation error occurred when an internal process is throwing some error. It looks like when a loop is running for all webs on one of the web you are not having an access and that may cause the issue, still I am not sure why it is not hitting the catch part.